# How can I add a SVG directly to my CSS file without modifying the HTML at all?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I am not allowed to modify the html of the page at all, so I was thinking on using a pseudo element like ::before or ::after and content:""; to add a svg made out of CSS only. How can I add it? The svg is this:

```html
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  width="300.000000pt" height="300.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 300.000000 300.000000"  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"> 
  <g transform="translate(0.000000,300.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#000" stroke="none">
    <path d="M756 2599 c-60 -14 -153 -68 -192 -111 -20 -22 -33 -42 -31 -45 3 -2 25 16 48 42 24 26 65 58 91 71 65 33 172 50 226 37 23 -6 42 -7 42 -3 0 19 -115 25 -184 9z"></path>
    <path d="M980 2575 c0 -2 17 -12 38 -22 53 -25 128 -103 154 -160 18 -39 22 -67 23 -148 0 -86 -3 -107 -24 -148 -32 -66 -100 -130 -174 -167 -34 -17 -51 -28 -37 -24 166 45 284 235 250 402 -13 63 -47 132 -88 179 -37 43 -142 108 -142 88z"></path> 
    <path d="M497 2383 c-33 -74 -31 -209 6 -284 45 -93 135 -170 227 -194 14 -3 -7 10 -47 30 -81 40 -132 92 -171 175 -35 73 -36 188 -4 268 27 65 19 69 -11 5z"></path>
    <path d="M1775 2371 c-44 -27 -63 -52 -73 -97 -21 -94 42 -174 137 -176 81 -1 141 59 141 143 0 109 -118 184 -205 130z m132 -17 c35 -22 63 -74 63 -114 0 -74 -61 -130 -141 -130 -35 0 -48 6 -80 39 -35 34 -39 44 -39 88 0 112 107 176 197 117z"></path>
    <path d="M2466 2176 c18 -8 37 -22 43 -33 6 -10 11 -13 11 -6 0 16 -49 53 -69 53 -9 -1 -2 -7 15 -14z"></path> 
    <path d="M2359 2153 c-13 -16 -12 -17 4 -4 9 7 17 15 17 17 0 8 -8 3 -21 -13z"></path>
    <path d="M2336 2113 c-6 -14 -5 -15 5 -6 7 7 10 15 7 18 -3 3 -9 -2 -12 -12z"></path>
    <path d="M2522 2090 c0 -19 2 -27 5 -17 2 9 2 25 0 35 -3 9 -5 1 -5 -18z"></path>
    <path d="M2340 2063 c0 -6 9 -21 21 -34 l20 -24 -17 30 c-24 39 -24 40 -24 28z"></path>
    <path d="M2487 2025 c-15 -14 -24 -25 -19 -25 5 0 19 11 32 25 30 32 23 32 -13 0z"></path>
    <path d="M803 1893 c26 -2 67 -2 90 0 23 2 2 3 -48 3 -49 0 -68 -1 -42 -3z"></path>
    <path d="M2080 1650 c-111 -21 -185 -121 -166 -224 10 -55 77 -123 139 -141 26 -8 47 -10 47 -5 0 6 -10 10 -22 10 -38 0 -106 48 -134 96 -33 55 -29 115 9 173 70 106 255 108 335 3 23 -30 27 -45 27 -97 0 -52 -5 -68 -28 -99 -27 -35 -64 -60 -117 -78 -20 -6 -18 -7 10 -3 81 12 150 92 150 175 0 123 -120 214 -250 190z"></path>
    <path d="M550 1240 c-216 -101 -183 -391 50 -441 102 -22 212 25 264 114 65 110 33 237 -77 309 -65 42 -168 50 -237 18z m169 0 c204 -58 224 -326 31 -413 -116 -52 -254 -5 -312 107 -30 59 -23 156 17 216 54 80 166 118 264 90z"></path>
    <path d="M1222 1205 c-21 -9 -38 -27 -48 -51 -43 -103 84 -188 157 -106 39 43 39 91 2 131 -34 37 -68 45 -111 26z m103 -31 c52 -56 17 -145 -58 -147 -79 -2 -120 91 -66 149 32 34 91 33 124 -2z"></path>
  </g> 
</svg>
```

Comment: The svg are circles only...

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
#fun::before {
 content: url("happy.svg");
}
```

Customize:

```
#yourId::before { 
content: url("yourImage.svg");
}
```